# Android MotionEven.Action_MOVE

Tags: java, android, motionevent, android-windowmanager

I have the following snippet of code (From this chathead [tutorial](https://blackmoont92.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/android-chathead-tutorial/)), the point of the last **switch** **case** is to handle the drag on the view, but I can't quit understand how the logic works :

```
        ...

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT ;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX()-initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

...
```

So when i'm going to click on my View with my finger and drag it to the Right by 4 params.x will receive O (the initialX) + 4 (since i moved it to x=4) - the initialTouchX (dont know the value of this variable at this moment), is this right ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your params.x will receive 0 (initial value) + 4 (moving delta), as this code only track delta change of finger move.

Comment: Okey ! So initialTouchX is 0  and will never change ?

Comment: No, initialTouchX initialized with raw X position of first finger touch (i.e. event.getRawX() in ACTION_DOWN) and after new position of finger subtracted each time (in ACTION_MOVE), so only delta calculated

Comment: Ok , lets say my view is at (x,y)(0,100) , i pushed my finger on the view and moved it by 4 to the right , when ACTION_DOWN , intialX will receive 0 initialTouchX will also receive 0 (since i pushed my finger on x  = 0) and then when moving calling ACTION_MOVE by delta 4 new event.getrawX will receive 4 : params.x = 0 + (4-0) = 4 ?

Comment: 'initialTouchX will also receive 0' - this isn't necessary true. event.getRawX() return x position in screen coordinate system, I guess (you can check this by logging in console). But actually it doesn't matter, because you interested only in delta of finger move.